# react redux firestore mapStateToProps issue while getting data

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

i am stuck in a very weird issue the issue is i am getting firestore collection like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Notification from './Notification'
import ProjectDetails from '../projects/ProjectDetails'
import ProjectList from '../projects/ProjectList'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { compose } from 'redux'

class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log('props are' , this.props);
        const {projects} = this.props.fireProjects;
        return (
            <div className="dashboard container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12 m6">
                        <ProjectList projects={projects} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col s12 m6">
                        <Notification />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log('from mstp' , state.firestore.ordered.projects);
    return {
        fireProjects : state.firestore.ordered.projects
    }
}
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    firestoreConnect([
        {collection : 'projects'}
    ])
    )(Dashboard)
```

when i console.log in mapStateToProps function i can see the firebaseProjects object having values but when i console.log in the component code this.props i see firebaseProjects : undefined . what should i do? i want to set the props of the component having firebaseProjects data coming from firestore . 
**the console result is**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this typo

```
const {projects} = this.props.firebaseProjects;

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log('from mstp' , state.firestore.ordered.projects);
    return {
        fireProjects : state.firestore.ordered.projects
   }
}
```

In `mapStateToProps` you named it `fireProjects` but you are accessing it in component as `firebaseProjects`

Comment: no no the error is not typo .. when we console.log(this.props) in the component in render function then we will see the props i have created , that is fireProjects is undefined ...